# Set correct value for each property in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a problem in pushing input into array. I have an array with some properties and I'm going to push some value into it, but I have no idea how to tell which value is for which property.

This is my array that I want to push into it:

```js
validInput: [{
  image: avatar1,
  name: '',
  email: '',
  passwrod: '',
  phone: '',
  revenue: '',
  create_date: '',
  age: '',
  id: ''
}]
```

This is my function that pushes into the array:

```js
validation(value, REGEX) {
  if (REGEX.test(value) === true) {
    this.state.validInput.push(value);
    this.setState({
      validInput: this.state.validInput
    });
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
}
```

Comment: So your expected output is an array of objects?

Comment: yes, but my array have only one object

Comment: Then just access it via... `validInput[0][PROPERTY] = VALUE`

Comment: I don't want to repeat it by writing property name! this is one function

Comment: So you just want to update existing object in the array?

Comment: If your array has  a single object, why have an array at all? Sounds like `validInput` should just be an object and you want to *merge* the old state with the new one. Can you provide a more complete example? What’s a potential value of `value` and what do you expect `validInput` to look like after “pushing” to it?

Comment: Seeing a more complete example of the component would help a lot as well. E.g. how the input fields are created and `validation` is called.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and you wish to convert your object inside validInput array into an array of objects you can do this:

Let's say we are looking to get an array of objects with the following format:

```
{keyName:key,keyValue:value}
```

we can do something like that:

```
const newArray = new Array();

Object.keys(this.validInput[0])
      .forEach(singleKey => {
          newArray.push({
                         keyName:singleKey,
                         keyValue:this.validInput[0][singleKey]
                       })
      })
// finally - we will have the newly formatted array in newArray
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have some unique way of identifying the object you want for filtering process like id, name etc. For modified function,

```
validation(id, value, REGEX) {
 if(REGEX.test(value)){
  this.state.validInput.map((user) => {
   if(user.id === id) {
     user.PROPERTY_YOU_NEED_TO_UPDATE = value
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Since this validInput might receive another object better use to identify it using `if(user.id === id)`. If validInput won't receive another there is no point to use array of objects.

```
validInput: {
  image: avatar1,
  name: '',
  email: '',
  passwrod: '',
  phone: '',
  revenue: '',
  create_date: '',
  age: '',
  id: ''
}
```

If it's like above you can just edit the property you want...

```
this.setState(state => {
  let user = Object.assign({}, state.validInput);  
  user.PROPERTY_YOU_NEED_TO_UPDATE = value;                                     
  return { user };                                 
})
```